# How to add Twig-Globals from custom bundle?

Tags: php, symfony, twig, symfony-bundle

In a Bundle I try to add a Twig-Global variable to be available in the app where the bundle is used. But it seems I am not allowed or miss something.

Why can't I access the `twig` parameters and add something? Or how should I do that?

Bundle: `./config/packages/twig.yaml`

```
# config/packages/twig.yaml
twig:
    # this should override the form_themes configuration:
    form_themes: ['@JohnCorpForms/forms/themes/bootstrap_4_layout_custom.html.twig']

    globals:
        # this should add some globals:
        testvar: 'foobar-linus'
        theme_ci: 'blue-grey'
        app_core: '@JohnCorpForms\Utils\Twig\AppTwigGlobals'
```

**Error Message**

> There is no extension able to load the configuration for "twig" (in "/var/www/myproject/vendor/johncorps/forms-bundle/src/DependencyInjection/../../config/packages/twig.yaml"). Looked for namespace "twig", found "none".

How I load the `twig.yaml` configuration file:

```
namespace JohnCorp\FormsBundle\DependencyInjection;

Rent2buyFormsExtension extends Extension
{
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $loader = new Loader\YamlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__ . '/../../config'));
        $loader->load(__DIR__ . '/../../config/packages/twig.yaml');
    }
}
```

*Sidnotes*

I tried different things to add the `twig.yaml` to the bundle configuration and have it loaded. According to the error it seems loaded, but to be honest I am a bit confused about how to extend other bundles yaml configuration (like in this case the twig-configuration). Use a compiler pass? Use YamlFileLoader? Use TreeNode? The documentation seems unclear about that or whereever you look you get different approaches (e.g. comparing other bundles approaches). So if anyone knows whats the easiest way to do this, I'd be happy to learn.

---

### Solution / Workaround

Here is my workaround (or maybe it's a proper solution?)

1. Add a custom TwigExtension, which implements `GlobalsInterface`
   *src/Utils/Twig/TwigExtension.php*

```
namespace JohnCorp\FormsBundle\Utils\Twig;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack;
use Twig\Extension\AbstractExtension;
use Twig\Extension\GlobalsInterface;

class TwigExtension extends AbstractExtension implements GlobalsInterface
{

    private RequestStack $requestStack;

    public function __construct(RequestStack $requestStack)
    {
        $this->requestStack = $requestStack;
    }

    public function getGlobals():array
    {
        return [
            'testvar': 'foobar-linus',
            'theme_ci': 'blue-grey',
            'app_core' => new AppTwigGlobals($this->requestStack),
        ];
    }
}
```

2. Load and wire this in Bundle-Class
   *src/JohnCorpFormsBundle.php*

```
class JohnCorpFormsBundle extends AbstractBundle
{
    public function loadExtension(array $config, ContainerConfigurator $container, ContainerBuilder $builder): void
    {
        parent::loadExtension($config, $container, $builder);

        $definition = $builder
            ->autowire('johncorpforms.twig_extension', TwigExtension::class)
            ->addTag('twig.extension');
    }
}
```

Now, when using the bundle in a project, I can access `app_core.{functionName}` everywhere!

---

PS: Of course I had to wire `$requestStack` for the `AppTwigGlobals::__construct()` in `services.yaml`

```
services:
    johncorpforms.twig_extension:
        class: JohnCorp\FormsBundle\Utils\Twig\TwigExtension
        arguments:
            $requestStack: '@request_stack'
```

Comment: $loader is for services not configuration.  It's easy to think they are the same because they look alike but it's really two completely different systems.  And yes the documentation is very confusing.  Your best bet would be a compiler pass which would add your variable to the twig globals.  There are some other questions on this topic with examples.  I have also seen it done using a kernel listener.

Comment: And while I personally have never had much luck with it, you might try giving [prepend extension](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/prepend_extension.html#prepending-extension-in-the-bundle-class) a try.

Comment: Thanks for your advices, I'll definately look into that. What did work(around) is loading a custom `TwigExtension` in `JohnCorpFormsBundle::loadExtension()` with tag `twig.extension` in which I provide the globals (e.g. `AppTwigGlobals` via `TwigExtension::getGlobals()` when implementing `GlobalsInterface`).